# find variable Declaration reference Abstract syntax tree eclipse cdt C code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a c code like this
`int x;
x = 5;`

I used eclipse cdt to generate the AST, and traverse on it, so this is the code of the traversed class

```
public class RuleChk extends AbstractRule {
    public RuleChk(IASTTranslationUnit ast) {
        super("RuleChk", false, ast);
        shouldVisitDeclarations = true;
        shouldVisitParameterDeclarations = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int visit(IASTSimpleDeclaration simpleDecl) {
        //if this node has init, e.g: x = 5, do business
        if(VisitorUtil.containNode(simpleDecl, CASTExpressionStatement){
           // Now I have the x = 5 node, 
           // I want to get the reference node of it's declaration
           // I mean (int x;) node
           IASTNode declNode = ?????
        }
        return super.visit(parameterDeclaration);
    }
}
```

what I want to visit the node that only has assignation(Initialization) and get the reference of declaration node for that varaiable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how `VisitorUtil` works (it's not from the CDT code), but I assume it gives you a way to access the the found node. So:

- Given the `IASTExpressionStatement` node that was found, use `IASTExpression.getExpression()` to get the contained expression.
- See if it's an `IASTBinaryExpression`, and that is `getOperator()` is `IASTBinaryExpression.op_assign`.
- Use `IASTBinaryExpression.getOperand1()` to get the assignment expression's left subexpression. Check that it's an `IASTIdExpression`, and get the variable it names via `IASTIdExpression.getName()`.
- Now that you have the name, use `IASTName.resolveBinding()` to get the variable's **binding**. This is the variable's representation in the semantic program model.
- To find the variable's definition, use `IASTTranslationUnit.getDefinitionsInAST(IBinding)` if you only want it to look in the current file, or `IASTTranslationUnit.getDefinitions(IBinding)` if you want it to look in included header files as well (the latter requires the project to be indexed). The `IASTTranslationUnit` can be obtained from any `IASTNode` via `IASTNode.getTranslationUnit()`.

Comment: I have done this before, but I need to get the declaration specifiers for the name, for the above example I want to return ( int )

Comment: @MostafaHassan Assuming the declaration is in the same file, `getDefinitionInAST()` will give you an `IASTName`. You can examine the surrounding AST to find the decl-specifiers. For example, the name's parent would be an `IASTDeclarator`, its parent an `IASTSimpleDeclaration`, and then you can use `IASTSimpleDeclaration.getDeclSpecifier()` to get the decl-specifier.

Answer (score 0):

like the answer above, but you can do it easiser using `IASTTranslationUnit.getReferences(IBinding)` which will give you all reference of `IASTName` to your `IBinding`, you can find the statement use `parent` method.